# Can't fix a memory leak in iPad App

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks, nsstring

I've used Instruments to locate the memory leak in my app but I just can't seem to fix it or find a workaround; it's my first app and first foray into Objective-C so I'm probably doing something fairly dumb. Can anyone help? I'm guessing the NSString object "str" isn't being released but how do I release it and then return it?

Here's the source code:

```
- (NSString *)MakeMsg:(uint8_t)slaveAddr FunctionCode:(uint8_t)functionCode StartReg: (uint16_t)startReg Range:(uint16_t)range {

NSString *str;

uint8_t CRCbyte1;
uint8_t CRCbyte2;
uint8_t buf[MODBUS_MSG_LEN_BYTES+LRC_BYTE+ASCII_WRAPPER];
uint8_t ASCIIbuf[(MODBUS_MSG_LEN_BYTES*2)+LRC_BYTE+ASCII_WRAPPER];  

buf[0] = slaveAddr;
buf[1] = functionCode;
buf[2] = (uint8_t)(startReg >> 8);
buf[3] = (uint8_t)(startReg & 0xFF);
buf[4] = (uint8_t)(range >> 8);
buf[5] = (uint8_t)(range & 0xFF);

if (RTUMode==YES){
    // calculate the CRC bytes 
    [self GenerateCRC16:buf CRC1:&CRCbyte1 CRC2:&CRCbyte2];
    buf[6] = CRCbyte1;
    buf[7] = CRCbyte2;
}

if (ASCIIMode==YES){
    // calculate the LRC byte
    [self GenerateLRC:buf Length:(uint8_t)MODBUS_MSG_LEN_BYTES ASCIIBuffer:ASCIIbuf];

    // convert the buffer to ASCII
    [self BufToASCII:buf ASCIIBuffer:ASCIIbuf];

    // add the ASCII wrapper ':',buf,'CR','LF'
    [self AddASCIIWrapper:buf ASCIIBuffer:ASCIIbuf];
}

str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)ASCIIbuf]; // <-- Memory leak identified as this line right here by Instruments
return str;// Return the string value of our command so we can use it in a comms log display.
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Matthew

Comment: If the leak is simple, Build and Analyze usually pinpoints it quite well.  You should try to fix any errors it finds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instruments only tells you where the leaked object was created. It can't tell you where you failed to release it (which is why the leak) because that could be anywhere.

Most likely you assign the string to a property of an object somewhere and fail to release it in that object's `-dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

`str` isn't a leak, or at least it's not being leaked in the code you posted. Since you create the string with +stringWithUTF8String:, you get back an autoreleased object. It's safe to return that object, and the caller will be able to use it, but it will eventually be released for you. If the caller is going to keep a reference to the string it receives from -MakeMSG, it should retain it.

Comment: Thanks JeremyP/Caleb. I didn't know that; I thought instruments actually pointed out where the leak occurring. It certainly explains why no amount of tweaking would get rid of the leak.